# netem packet loss in TCP/IP protocol

Tags: linux, sockets, networking

I'm trying to emulate packet loss for my project. I'm using TCP/IP protocol. `netem` tool provides such functionality. The delay works in the loopback IP but I couldn't make packet loss to work. According to the website of `netem`, the packet loss is activated as follows:

```
tc qdisc change dev lo root netem loss 5%
```

In the client/server app using TCP/IP socket in c programming, the client sends this message "Echo this !", the echoed message from the server received by the client is intact. As far as I know, TCP/IP guarantees the delivery of packets. Is emulating packet loss impossible with TCP/IP protocol?

Comment: TCP applications will never see packet loss, the TCP protocol performs automatic retransmission transparently. If you want to detect packet loss you should use UDP.

Comment: @Barmar this is what I thought. Thank you so much!

Comment: You can still emulate packet loss, and you'll see the results in the retransmission statistics in `netstat`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the packet is lost, TCP will send it again after some delay. If it gets lost again, it will send it again. And so on, up to a maximum of 10 minutes or so, after which it just gives up.

5% packet loss is *not completely terrible* and your message is likely to get through after one or two resends - or zero. Also notice your whole message fits in a packet, so your programs only send a few packets in total (your message plus extra ones to connect and disconnect) and it's quite likely that *none* of them will be lost.

You can try sending a longer message (like a megabyte), and you can try cranking the packet loss up to 25% or 50% (or even higher!). It should take a lot longer to send the message, even without any delay in the network, but your message should get through *eventually*, unless TCP decides to just give up and disconnect you.